# Can you block manual share for a specific user?

Tags: apex, sharing

I've been doing some research and wanted to see if it's possible to block manual share on a specific object to a user. Any ideas?

I did some research, and you cannot put a trigger on a the corresponding Share Object. I also looked into Transaction Security, but didn't find support for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is you schedule a job to periodically remove them. A nightly/hourly batch should do the trick.